# Studying versus doing

Tags: torah-study, mitzvah

In commenting on Leviticus 26:14, Or HaChaim argues that if you study the details of the sacrifices today, when you cannot actually do them, you have fulfilled the commandments on sacrifices **better** than if the Temple stood and you sacrificed as commanded without really knowing all the details.  Given this teaching, why can't intense Torah study of any commandment substitute for its actual performance, even when it CAN be performed?

Comment: The question would seemingly be a good question for sacrifices. However, given that we have no source for this idea for other commandments, I don't think the question applies there

Comment: There is such an idea that when one does a mitzvah in actuality they can never do it b'shlemusa (in completness) since a human cannot achieve perfection. However,if one desires to do a mitzvah then HaShem considers it as one did it,and since it is coming from HaShem it is considerd complete, so in a way it is on a higher level,however this is only done when one cannot physically do the mitzvah. I believe this is from Reb Yonason Eibschitz,need to find it.